# Making a program to play multiple sine waves at a time by keyboard press on python

Tags: python, multithreading

To get this out of the way: I am basically a newborn when it comes to coding, but for some reason I decided to do a coding project for a seminar class at university. I'm using Pycharm and trying to make a program that plays sounds based on keypress but am stuck at being able to have multiple tones play at a time.

This is what I cuurently have:

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import math
import struct
import keyboard

FS = 44100  #  frames per second, samples per second or sample rate

def play_sound(type, frequency, volume, duration):

   generate_sound(type, frequency, volume, duration)

def generate_sound(type, frequency, volume, duration):

    outbuf = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=int(float(duration / 1000.0)*FS))

    if type == "sine":
        dur = int(FS * float(duration / 1000.0))
        theta = 0.0
        incr_theta = frequency * 2 * math.pi / FS # frequency increment normalized for sample rate
        for i in range(dur):
            outbuf[i] = volume * math.sin(theta)
            theta += incr_theta

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32, channels=1, rate=FS, output=True)
    data = b''.join(struct.pack('f', samp) for samp in outbuf) # must pack the binary data
    stream.write(data)
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

#thread here maybe?

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
        play_sound("sine",200, 0.5, 3000)
    if keyboard.is_pressed("s"):
        play_sound("sine",300,0.5,3000)
    elif keyboard.is_pressed("esc"):
        break
```

What it does right now is play a note when I press either "a" or "s", but I must wait until the tone is over before starting another note. Any help would be appreciated, and I really respect people who know how to do this stuff haha.

Edit:I now realize that the tones can't add together by themselves. I think I will create a new function that adds the two waves and activates when I press both buttons at the same time. I hope this works. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Work through your program one line at a time. Where do you think multiple tones could be played at once? You should find that the tone for "a" starts and completes before your program can even attempt to check that "s" has been pressed.

Comment: The typical approach to playing multiple tones would be to sum the samples of the two tones together into a buffer, and then pass the summed buffer out to the audio device.  Combining tones by calling `play_sound()` twice could only work if `play_sound()` returns before the sound has finished, *and* if something in the `play_sound()` implementation is willing to do the summing/mixing for you (and I don't think either of those conditions is present here)

Comment: Instead of playing 2 sounds, you could play the combined sound. Would that work for you?

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone! I think what I'll do is create a combined tone and bind that to a different key, and that should accomplish what I need this program to do.